# "Delete" keyboard shortcut in Eclipse Babel

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In my RCP application that includes Eclipse Babel plugins I have encountered the same problem as described here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/239897/
("Delete" keyboard shortcut in menu and in tooltips is internationalized).
I would like to fix it by editing Eclipse Babel jars. I thought I had found it in *AbstractKeyFormatter_ru.properties* from *org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys* package (org.eclipse.ui.workbench.nl_ru_[version].jar), but I was mistaken. Where can I find keyboard shortcuts i18n?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, keyboard shortcuts i18n is hidden in *AbstractKeyFormatter_[nl].properties* from *org.eclipse.jface.bindings.keys.formatting* package (org.eclipse.jface.nl_[nl][version].jar)